# Local Notifications in Cordova 3.0.0

Tags: android, ios, mobile, cordova, push-notification

I am developing a Cordova 3.0.0 application which needs to periodically show notifications to the user. They need to be the kind of notifications that live in the notification center on iOS; modal popups aren't good enough as the app may be running in the background at the time.

The built-in Notification plugin only provides modal popups: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html

I have seen 3rd party plugins, such as this: https://github.com/DrewDahlman/Phonegap-LocalNotification
- however, they are developed for much older versions of Cordova/PhoneGap.

Is it possible to use any of these with Cordova 3; or is there a better way to do it (device-independently if at all possible, as I need to have similar behaviour on Android as well as iOS); or would my best option be to downgrade to an older version of Cordova?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Drew Dalhman's Plugin still has some Issues. For example **cancel()** and **background callback** do not work.

---

### This one, from Sebastián Katzer is updated and **works** with **Cordova 3+** :

**https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications**

for iOS, Android and WP8

Comment: This is the best one I have used so far, and the only one that seems to support multiple platforms.

Comment: Indeed it is. I am using it as well. Unfortunately one can't donate to his work. I also did not find any software Sebastian sells. Hopefully he keeps this plugin alive.

Comment: I added Katzer but what are these errors?
`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/js/device.js:22`
`Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/js/local-notification.js:184`
`Uncaught ReferenceError: device is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/js/local-notification.js:85`

Comment: @Babak Common error. Please make sure you point to the js file in your index.html file. Also make sure the js file is in the plugins folder, if you added the plugin via CLI. Sometimes it does not copy the file into the directory.

Comment: @FlyingLemon Should I point to pliugins' folder js? I've copied js files to Android's asset folder and then pointed to those files in index.html. I've checked the addresses and they were correct.

Comment: @Babak you using phonegap 2.x.x?

Comment: @BlackPearl, No, its v3. My problem has been solved by updating the plug-in.

Comment: @Babak ok, i was searching for a compatible 2.9/2.9.1 plug-in yesterday but I ended up writing my own and it is very, very good.

Comment: @FlyingLemon: I am referencing the js file by: <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="local-notification.js"></script> and the local-notification.js lies in plugins/de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification/www. Still, I am getting the reference error. Why?

Answer (score 1):

According to the issues for Drew Dalhman's plugin some people have had some success using that plugin in Cordova 3.0.6:

https://github.com/DrewDahlman/Phonegap-LocalNotification/issues/18

Rather than downgrading to an earlier version I'd look to see if a pull request can be created for the plugin. This will help everyone and will allow you to take advantage of Cordova improvements.

I was actually researching this same issue earlier for Android. Not implemented anything yet, but this tutorial seems to have some useful information (Part 3 is most relevant to showing notifications):

http://red-folder.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/phonegap-service-tutorial-part-1.html

Comment: This is good. Specifically, the user "hiattp" (who commented on that issue a few times) created a fork that implements it as a plugin that works a lot better on Cordova 3: https://github.com/hiattp/Phonegap-LocalNotification

It still requires some manual steps (see linked readme), but is a lot closer.

Answer (score 0):

I googled but couldn't find anything.

My suggestion would be that you write your own plugins/extensions for Android and IOS respectively. It isn't difficult. The problem with writing your own IOS plugin is that you need to have a mac and iphone/ipad. Also, try the Phonegap-LocalNotification plugin you mention, it could possibly work.